# Outlook addin: 'ExtendedPermissions' in manifest XML to use 'AppendOnSend' function (Office.Body.appendOnSendAsync API)

Tags: outlook-addin, manifest

I get an error when I add the 'ExtendedPermissions' in my add-in manifest to use 'AppendOnSend' function (Office.Body.appendOnSendAsync API):

The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'ExtendedPermissions' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'. List of possible elements expected: any element in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'.

My XML:

```
 ...
 <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      ...
    </Requirements>
    <Host>
      ...
    </Host>
    <Resources>
      ...
    </Resources>
    <ExtendedPermissions>
      <ExtendedPermission>AppendOnSend</ExtendedPermission>
    </ExtendedPermissions>
  </VersionOverrides>
 ...
```

What am I doing wrong in the XML?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Comment: What requirement set did you specify in the manifest?

Comment: I have:   <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

Comment: You need to set it to 1.8.